# Javascript- Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function escapeHtml(text) {

      return text
        .replace(/\t/g, "")
        .replace(/\n/g, "")
        .replace(/%/g,"")
        .replace(/\s/g, " ")
        .replace(/&/g, "")
        .replace(/</g, "")
        .replace(/>/g, "")
}
```

can somebody provide me the regex for all the above entities into a single regex?

Comment: Can you create example you want, I think your method wrong
`'<div>something</div>' -> 'divsomething/div'`

Comment: Did you really mean to replace `\s` with a space, instead of with an empty string like all the rest?

Comment: `\s` is the same as space, `\t`, and `\n`. but you already replaced `\t` and `\n` earlier.

Answer (score 4):

If `\s` is being replaced  with a space, while all the others are being replaced with the empty string, it's not possible with a single regex unless you provide it with a replacer function, which doesn't make much sense - just use two `.replace`s. To be concise, use a character set:

```
return text
  .replace(/[\t\n%&<>]/g, '')
  .replace(/\s/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
text.replace(/[&%$<>\t\s]/g,"");
```

replace all enter, whitespaces & tabs with `\s` and `\t`
and character `&%$<>`